# How to remove currency symbol in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can anybody tell how to remove the currency symbol in AngularJS?

```
value = $filter('currency')(value);
```

I am getting a dollar symbol. I want to remove it.

Comment: Can you show more of your codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass empty string as second argument to the filter function.

```
value = $filter('currency')(value, "");
```

Also you can inject `currencyFilter` itself. You do not have to derive it from the filter Factory, with that you would just do:

```
value = currencyFilter(value, "");
```

[Note the syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency#Arguments):

> $filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)

Comment: I get this error when trying to use `currencyFilter`. The error is `ReferenceError: currencyFilter is not defined`

Answer (score 16):

I sadly don't yet have the required reputation to comment on an answer, but Samuel's answer needs a slight tweak. Just add the empty quotes, not value="".

```
<div> {{20 | currency:""}} </div>
```

Likewise you can use this same approach to override the dollar sign with any character, in this case pounds sterling:

```
<div> {{20 | currency:"&#163;"}} </div>
```

or even use the named representation rather than the decimal:

```
<div> {{20 | currency:"&pound"}} </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You also can do it in view with just pass empty string after currency filter.

```
<div> {{20 | currency:value=""}} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use space code;

{{20 | currency:"*&nbsp*"}}

&nbsp ; is space character. 
you can change &nbsp character

Comment: I am using Angular 6/7 have to use semicolon  ;   to &nbsp; like this

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular 6/7 
by this you can empty the currency symbol like this

```
{{product?.price | currency:'&nbsp;'}}
```

Comment: this inserts a space character, so the number is not aligned correctly